# How to prevent iFrame actions from causing outer page to scroll to it

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser, scroll

First, I know there are many questions about this phenomenon but none of the workarounds given so far would help in the situation I have here.

[image]

**Environment:** 
My code is in the Outer iFrame inside a page I don't control. It's sized to fit all my content so no scrolling happens inside my iFrame. Rather, the outer page can scroll it up and down to view its content.

**Problem:**
I have an inner iFrame holding third party ads which I can't control. If the inner iFrame runs any of the following Javascript commands, the outer page scrolls everything down to bring the inner iFrame into view:

1. blur and focus on an element inside it
2. window.location.href or document.location.hash to an anchor inside it.
3. scrollIntoView on an element inside it

[Here is a demo a colleague put together](http://zchan0-a.akamaihd.net/test/allyourscrollarebelongtous/0.0.1/index.html) (wait 5 seconds for it to start)

**Solutions that don't work:**

1. If I controlled the outer page, I could listen to the onScroll event and prevent the page from scrolling if it wasn't from a mousewheel or key up/down event. However, due to security reasons, my outer iFrame can't access the main page or prevent the main page from scrolling it up or down.
2. I could overwrite all those Javascript methods mentioned above so they didn't work - however, the ads in my inner iFrame actually create their own internal iFrames which have that functionality and causes the same issue.
3. There are no events being propagated up that I can see which my iFrame could stop from reaching the main page. The browser appears to listen directly to the innermost iFrame.

Comment: Can you try sandboxing the child iframe? I realize this is probably not a solution since ads most likely need to run scripts, but perhaps worth experimenting? Perhaps add a sandbox attribute after iframe content loaded?

Comment: Yeah I tried that and the only sandboxing setting that seems to work is totally disabling javascript which isn't an option since the ads need to run scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there are some other ways to solve this issue, but one pretty straightforward solution is to take troublesome iframes out of the natural layout of the site by **positioning them as `fixed`**.

Then the only remaining challenge may be to *force* them to behave as if they were part of the natural layout. But this tasks seems to be of mediocre complexity in comparison to the original problem.

Moreover, in your particular case, the above approach works pretty out of the box. Since the outer iframe is not scrollable and its height matches its content height: you just need to insert -- for each iframe -- a placeholder that matches its counterpart size...

Comment: But the only IFRAME op can control is inner iframe, and I don't think that's enough

Comment: @YuriyGalanter from what I understand inner iframes contain ads and may misbehave, outer iframe is controlled by op and the most top context is outside of his control. I created such a setting and the result looks pretty promising.

Comment: If I understand correctly outer frame's HTML content is controlled by the OP, not how outer IFRAME is defined in main outer page. Might be mistaken though

Comment: This was it! Changing the inner iFrame to fixed positioning cancels the problem entirely. Your idea about putting a placeholder there also is a great idea and I realized we could use Javascript to dynamically set the top of the fixed iFrame to the top of the dummy element so that it still appears in the same place within the outer iFrame.

Answer (score 1):

If you can drop IE10 and below support and the `iframes` are same domain, you could use a combination of you solution number 2 (rewrite the methods) and `mutation` events. 
You'd need to first iterate through all `iFrames` already in the DOM and remove unwanted functions, and maybe also clear unwanted intervals. And on each `document` you add a `mutation` `observer` that will run the same scripts on `added nodes` if they are `iFrames`. So you'd have a recursive function going through all iframes at the beginning, and a function to remove methods, clear intervals and add observers on each `iFrame`. And once an `iFrame` is added, you run the same thing on it.Something like this:

The recursive function:

```
var to_cancel = ["scrollIntoView","blur","focus"];
window.onload = function(){iterate_window_object(window)};
function iterate_window_object(cur_win){
    remove_methods(cur_win);
    for(var i=0;i<cur_win.frames.length;i++){
        remove_methods(cur_win.frames[i])
         if(cur_win.frames[i].length>0){
              iterate_window_object(cur_win.frames[i])
           }

      }
   }
```

The cleaning function:

```
function remove_methods(cur_win){ 
      for(var j=0;j<to_cancel.length;j++){
           cur_win.Element.prototype[to_cancel[j]] = {}
       }

       for (var k = 0; k < 999;k++){
            cur_win.clearInterval(k);
       }
       cur_win.setInterval = {};
       cur_win.observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
             mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                  for(var k=0;k<mutation.addedNodes.length;k++){
                       var added_node = mutation.addedNodes[k]
                       if(added_node.tagName == "IFRAME"){
                            remove_methods(added_node.contentWindow);
                            added_node.contentWindow.onload = function(){iterate_window_object(added_node.contentWindow)};
                        }
                   };
                });    
            });
            cur_win.config = { childList: true };
              cur_win.observer.observe(cur_win.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], cur_win.config);

        }
```

There's probably a way to make it look better, the hardest part is being able to modify the methods before they get called. And here it's a bit overkill because it iterates through new `iFrames` so that if an iframe is added with already added `iFrames`, they are also taken car of. It's probably not necessary.
So it could maybe be a solution, but `mutation` events aren't supported by IE10 and below.

Comment: Wow - thanks so much for the thorough answer! I didn't test it since Artur's worked so simply but seems like this would also work.